# Error In LINQ to Entities attempting to join two result sets

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to select the results of two entity objects using a JOIN in my LINQ query as such:

```
Dim r = (From a In db.appointments Join e In dba.config On a.event_id Equals e.event_ID
       Where a.create_timestamp > LastRunTime And a.create_timestamp <= CurrentRunTime And a.appt_date > strDate _
        And a.cancel_flag = "N" And a.resched_flag = "N" And a.delete_ind = "N" _
        And (e.enableNotify = True Or e.enableRegistration = True)).ToList()
```

This gives me the following error:

*This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.*

I've not seen this error before, is my issue in the .ToList(), and am i required to select into an anonymous type? such as:

```
.Select(function (o) New With {Key .ID = a.ID, Key .event_id = e.event_id}).ToList()
```

Why does the .ToList() not just generate an anon type from the two entity objects automatically?

Comment: I assume db and dba are both different database contexts which is probably what's causing the issue.